# Show / Hide colspan a specific row at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a problem, I need to show / hide a `colspan` of each column when a link is clicked.

That is to say, I have many records, and when you click on any specific, need to show this information on a `colspan`, when another record is clicked hide the record previously clicked.

My HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover text-center">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
        <?php foreach ($products as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td>10000</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="1">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Product 2</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="2">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Details of selected product</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I had this code, but always brought me the first record:

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle('slow');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('td #colspanid').append(id); //show id
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It will be good if you post the `HTML` rendered in your browser!!

Comment: Not even know where to start, my command of jQuery is very basic.

Comment: @CristianMezaBustos then you should start with learning jQuery basics. Documentation, books, tutorials and so on.

Comment: Atleast some records to test it up in jsfiddle

Comment: Ready, sorry for my mistakes when creating the question. Greetings !!.

Comment: @CristianMezaBustos I don't understand what for you want to hide table rows (how will you click _Show details_ on hidden row?), but without this part [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtremy1a/) is what I think is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific row to toggle then you can use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.show').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         // Put row index in eq
         $('.table tr').eq(2).toggle();
    })
})
```

Or if you want to toggle next tr then check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96ffmqbd/) that i've created.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks for your answer. As I do to display the information just below the record clicked and not under the table? I appreciate your help very much. Greetings !!.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the click function like this.

```
 $('.show').click(function(){
var element1=$(this);
$('.previous').addClass('hide');
element1.parent().parent().addClass('previous'); 

    var id = element1.attr('id');
    $('td#colspn').text('Details of selected product is :' +id); //show id
    return false;
});
```

and add css:

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Play the below html for reference.

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
var element1=$(this);
$('.previous').addClass('hide');
element1.parent().parent().addClass('previous'); 

    var id = element1.attr('id');
    $('td#colspn').text('Details of selected product is :' +id); //show id
    return false;
});
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover text-center">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
       
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td>10000</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="1">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Product 2</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="2">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td>10000</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="3">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Product 2</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="show" id="4">Show details</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="colspn" colspan="5">Details of selected product</td>
            </tr>
       
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks for your answer. This is what I want, but when I show the information for a record, and then I click another, I need is to hide the information from the record that had clicked above, no need to hide the entire row, sorry if misunderstood.
I also like to display the information just below the record clicked and not under the table? I appreciate your help very much. Greetings !!.

Answer (score 0):

First, identify the details rows by giving them a class.

```
<tbody> 
    <?php foreach ($products as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[3] ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="show" id="<?php echo $row[0] ?>">Show details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="details">  <!-- <<<<< class="details" -->
            <td colspan="5">Details of selected product</td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<tbody>
```

Then, the jQuery will be as follows :

```
$(function() {
    $("tr.details").hide().closest("tbody").find("a.show").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//prevent hyperlink action
        $("tr.details").slideUp('fast');//hide any previously opened details
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr.details").slideDown('fast');//show details for the clicked row
    });
});
```